# Return Object Key based on Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to return the key of an object based on the greatest value of its `object[value]`. For example:

```js
const myObj = {
    a: 100,
    b: 200,
    c: 300
}
```

I need a function that would return `c` (given that `c` has the highest numerical value)

Comment: `Object.entries(myObj).sort((a, b) => (a[1] - b[1]))[0][0]` <-- please try this.

Comment: b[1] - a[1] for the highest numerical value

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? You declared a literal constant (!O.0), do you mean that your object needs to change values and/or you need it assorted ?

Comment: @dnaatwork.com Yes, the values will change. My actual problem is that I'm trying to remove outliers from a dataset for K-Means analysis. I want to have a handler to remove the datapoints with the highest values (e.g. click once and remove the highest y-value datapoint, click twice and click the second highest y-value datapoint).

Comment: So, in effect when you supply input as `myObj = {a: 100, b: 200, c: 300};` you require a result like so: `{a: 100, b: 200}` - is that it? Essentially, the data-point c: 300 is now removed? And what happens if: `myObj = {a: 100, b: 200, c: 300, d: 300};` - should both c & d be considered outliers & removed?

Comment: @jsN00b That's a really good point.

Comment: So @jsN00b any suggestions?

Comment: My thoughts are that the odds of two datapoints being identical (scale is 8) are slim, however, I don't like playing the odds.

Comment: @jsN00b Your first comment worked! I am using MobX and just assigned the return from that to a local variable and then filtered it out using `Object.Keys()`. Thanks a bunch man! BTW... I would upvote it but I don't have the SO privs. =)

Comment: One thing about my last comment, @dellink is right, it needs to be `b[1] - a[1]` to return the highest value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(myObj).reduce((acm, current) => {
    if (acm) {
        return myObj[acm] > myObj[current] ? acm : current;
    }
    return current;
}, null);
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how your code solves the problem, rather than just pasting the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
const myObj = {
    a: 100,
    b: 200,
    c: 300
};
res = Object.keys(myObj).sort((b,a) => myObj[a]-myObj[b]);
console.log(res); // [ "c", "b", "a" ]
// for highest use res[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fn(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((v, maximum) => maximum[1] < v[1] ? v : maximum)[0]
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Comment: Okay, Thank you! I will consider it more.

Answer (score 1):

```
   function getMaxValueKey(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b);
}
```

[Reference](https://michaelmovsesov.com/articles/get-key-with-highest-value-from-javascript-object)